# Cutting a rectangle in pieces

Tags: geometry

We have to cut  a rectangle of size `(MxN)` into 3 pieces such that each pieces has a area `a ,b and c` respectively.How can we tell it's possible or not.

```
One condition is: M*N = a+b+c
```

Is there any other condition ?

Comment: Cut it into three rectangles: M by a/M, M by b/M, and M by c/M.

Comment: no other conditions unless you require the divisions to be integer sized.

Comment: Smells like somebody is trying to cheat in [this online contest](https://www.codechef.com/SNCKEL16/problems/VCAKE)

Answer (score 2):

Yes,you can do so as long as the areas work out. You can do two different patterns, shown below.[image]  Either will always work.  If the vertical dimension is $M$, the horizontals are $a/M, b/M, c/M$, which are guaranteed to add to $N$ by the area condition.  On the right, the right rectangle is $M \times c/M$ (or any of the letters).  Then the horizontal on the left is $N-c/M$ and the verticals are $\frac b{N-c/M}, \frac a{N-c/M}$